# What is this interface icon mean in Gmail?

Tags: gmail, email

What does the question mark icon next to the sender's email in Gmail stand for?

I have been able to deduct what the X and the exclamation mark stand for but can't figure it out with the question mark.

[image: screenshot of Gmail icon]

Answer (score 1):

This is a 2016 Gmail feature.  It indicates that Gmail can't confirm the sender's identity.  In other words, Gmail is telling you that the email *could* be from a different sender than it says it's from.

[Here is the Google support article on the feature.](https://support.google.com/mail/answer/180707?hl=en&ref_topic=3404236)

[Here is the original announcement.](https://blog.google/products/gmail/making-email-safer-for-you-posted-by/?m=1)